# Eclipse SDK getFileForLocation returns null though file is in the workspace

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp

I'm writing a plugin for Eclipse. As part of the plugin, I'm just trying to get the IFile for a file in my workspace. To do this, I use `ResourcesPlugin.getWorkspace().getRoot().getFileForLocation(path)`, but this doesn't seem to be working at all.

Here's the simplest possible test case. I have an action that does the following:

```
IPath path = new Path("C:/Programming/runtime-New_configuration/slackbot-resistance/README.md");
IFile toOpen = ResourcesPlugin.getWorkspace().getRoot().getFileForLocation(path);
```

I'm running this in the workspace at `Programming/runtime-New_configuration`. I have included the "slackbot-resistance" project in this workspace. There is a `README.md` file in the workspace. I can open that file in Eclipse successfully by manually clicking on it.

But `toOpen` always ends up as `null`. I don't get it. I'm passing it an absolute path to a file in one of the projects in the current workspace, as it tells me to, but it's returning null. Is this method bugged or just sorely lacking in documentation?

Comment: What does `ResourcesPlugin.getWorkspace().getRoot().getLocation().toOSString()` report?

Comment: C:\Programming\runtime-New_configuration

Comment: Actually if you open the 'Properties' for the file the 'Resources' tab has a 'Location' value which is what `getFileForLocation` will be trying to match.

Comment: The location value for that file is C:\Programming\slackbot-resistance\README.md. Odd. I did initially create the project outside of the workspace, but I then I imported it into the workspace. When I did this, it copied all of the files into the workspace. I see all of the project files in my filesystem inside of the workspace, including the one I'm trying to programatically find. So why is the "location" value for this file pointing at the original file location and not the new location inside the workspace?

Comment: Is the type shown in the properties 'Linked File'? It is possible to create a link to a file outside of the workspace.

Comment: To cross-check you could see if 'findFilesForLocationURI()` returns anything?